# Year-old report suddenly starts giving a 1004 run-time error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not a programmer so I am unable to figure out what's wrong. Please help! This is the code that is being used:

```
'allcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("All Billing").Range("A:A")) + 1
ac = AllBill.Cells(allcount - 1, 1)

For ar = 2 To SPA Step 1       
  'InvNum
  AllBill.Cells(allcount, 1) = ac + 1    '<-- error appears on this line

  'Date
  cp = Display.Cells(ar, 2)  
  AllBill.Cells(allcount, 2) = cp

  'InvMonth
  AllBill.Cells(allcount, 3) = YrMoDisplay(cp)
```

Comment: the code is incomplete (you can see the start of the loop but not the end). Please post the correct section of the code. Also, how is "AllBill" set?

Comment: A shot in the dark: Check the value of `allcount` It may be `0`

Comment: It appears you've commented out the assignment to `allcount` variable. If that variable is 0 (an unassigned variable will evaluate to 0) or negative, then the error 1004 would be expected.  If the problem was with `AllBill` not set properly, I'd expect 424 Object Required error.  So probably the problem has to do with `allcount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the apostrophe before the first line 'allcount' and this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you click the tick on the left to mark this as the answer to this question. Glad i could help :)